# LINQ string contain any element of a list of string (ASP net core MVC)

Tags: c#, string, linq, asp.net-core-mvc

In the Dat Access Layer of an ASP.NET Core MVC project, I need to get a list of "news" matching with any tags passed as parameter, something like:

```
public List<News> GetNewsByTags(List<String> tagsList)
{
    return database.News.Where(news => news.Tags.ContainsAnyElementOf(tagsList));
}
```

but I didn't succeed to make something like this work.
For information, this is my request for only one tag:

```
public List<News> GetNewsByTag(String tag)
{
    return database.News.Where(news => news.Tags.Contains(tag)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Is `news.Tag` a string or a list of strings?

Comment: news.Tags is a string build like that : `"tag1;tag2;tag3"`

Comment: Ok, that explains the error. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `Tags` is a single string with semicolons, you should do it in two phases: first, query on the SQL side with `Contains`, then filter what comes back to avoid false positives:

```
var preliminary = database.News
    .Where(news => tagsList.Any(t => news.Tags.Contains(t)))
    .ToList();
var tagSet = new HashSet<string>(tagList);
return preliminary.Select(news => new {
    News = news
,   MatchCount = news.Tags.Split(';').Count(t => tagSet.Contains(t))
}).Where(p => p.MatchCount > 0)
.OrderByDescending(p => p.MatchCount)
.Select(p => p.News);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to check that any of the news tag appears in the list of tags given. That translates quite literally to LINQ:

```
database.News.Where(news =>
    tagsList.Any(tag => news.Tags.Contains(tag))
)
```

Comment: I got an error on the `news.Tags.Split(';')` : 
An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Comment: @Alexis, just figured it can be rewritten in other way, see updated version

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
var allInCollection = news.Tags.Any(x => tagsList.Contains(x));
```